# Android RelativeLayout как сделать 4 CardView, которые ресайзятся и занимают по 25% экрана не зависимо от наполнения

Tags: android

Как при помощи `RelativeLayout`сделать 4 CardView, которые ресайзятся и занимают по 25% экрана не зависимо от наполнения

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_all">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/understockCard"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/overview_cards_corner_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/overview_cards_cardElevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/overview_cards_contentPadding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UNDERSTOCK"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/nearReorderCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/understockCard"

        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/overview_cards_corner_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/overview_cards_cardElevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/overview_cards_contentPadding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t12"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NEAR REORDER"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/properLevelsCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:layout_below="@+id/understockCard"

        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/overview_cards_corner_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/overview_cards_cardElevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/overview_cards_contentPadding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PROPER LEVELS"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/overstockCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:layout_below="@+id/nearReorderCard"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/properLevelsCard"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/overview_cards_corner_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/overview_cards_cardElevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/overview_cards_contentPadding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OVERSTOCK"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Так и сделал. Напишите ответ, а я его приму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека поддержки от Google - [*Percent Support Library*](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/). Она реализует классы контейнеров, в которых можно указать расстояния и размеры для вложенных элементов в процентах от размера самого контейнера.
Класс [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) из этой библиотеки решит вашу проблему наиболее просто.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно странное желание. Почему бы не взять `LinearLayout` и раздать всем одинаковый `layout_weight` при `android:layout_height="0dp"` ?

Но если прямо уж такое желание сделать все на `RelativeLayout`, первое что пришло в голову: размещаем в центр невидимую вьюшку и от нее пляшем. Разметка и результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все `card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen` и прочее убрал, ато и так много текста. Добавите необходимое.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/centerRLRoot">
        <View android:id="@+id/centerRLOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/understockCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/centerRLOne"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNDERSTOCK"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/understockCard2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/understockCard">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNDERSTOCK"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerRLRoot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <View android:id="@+id/centerRLTwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/understockCard3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/centerRLTwo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNDERSTOCK"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/understockCard4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/understockCard3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNDERSTOCK"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```